# Value is not returning form function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner and I am learning JavaScript. I am trying to return a value from a function but I am not getting the value. When I am doing `console.log(randomNuber)` it is showing `undefined`. Also, it is not showing anything for the last line of the JavaScript code.

```js
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
    var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");

    function randomDigit() {
        var randomEl = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
        randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomEl;
        return randomEl;
    }

    var randomNumber = generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", randomDigit);
    console.log("Random Number is:", randomNumber);
    console.log(randomNumberDisplayEl.value);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Pin Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/raw/upload/v1628938996/StackOverflow/style_til9dq.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pin-generator half-width">
                        <input class="form-control" id="random-number-display" type="text">
                        <button class="generate-btn" id="generate-btn">Generate Pin</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="notify-section pb-3" id="notify-section">
                <p class="notify" id="notify-wrong">❌ Pin Didn't Match, Please try again</p>
                <p class="notify" id="notify-right">✅ Pin Matched... Secret door is opening for you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Why I am getting the value of `randomNumber`? Also not getting anything for the last line `randomNumberDisplayEl.value`.

**Actually, I need the `randomNumber` as a global variable so that I can use it anywhere in the program.**

How can I get the value of `randomNumber` outside of function `randomDigit`?

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Events don't return any value, you've to assign the value to `randomNumber` in the event handler function.

Comment: `addEventListener` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You have assigned randomNumber to the result of the call to addEventListener. [This method returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). This is not a direct call to the method randomDigit. You can add log statements inside randomDigit to see the number returned.

Comment: `addEventListener` returns `undefined`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value

Comment: Actually, I need the `randomNumber` as a global variable so that I can use it anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to  be a bit of confusion between what is an element and what is an 'ordinary' variable value, like a number in this case.

In this code:

```
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");

function randomDigit() {
    var randomEl = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
    randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomEl;
    return randomEl;
}

var randomNumber = generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", randomDigit);
console.log("Random Number is:", randomNumber);
console.log(randomNumberDisplayEl.value);
```

randomNumberDIsplayEl and generateBtnEl both correctly are elements (hence the El at the end).

However randomEl is set to be a random number. I suggest this be renamed, say to what it is: randomNumber.

Then in the above code, randomNumber is assigned from something (an addEventListener) that doesn't return anything. What we need to do is add the event listener and then in the function called when the user clicks (randomDigit) that is when the random number can be looked at.

The function is named as if it were getting a digit, so I've renamed it to what it is doing, getRandomNumber to try to make the sequence of events clearer.

So the above code becomes:

```
var randomNumber; //make it global
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");

function getRandomNumber() {
    randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
    randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomNumber;    
    console.log("Random Number is:", randomNumber);
    console.log(randomNumberDisplayEl.value);
    return randomEl;
}

generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", getRandomNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var notifyWrongEl = document.getElementById("notify-wrong");
var notifyRightEl = document.getElementById("notify-right");
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");

// Notifications Hide
notifyWrongEl.style.display = "none";
notifyRightEl.style.display = "none";

function randomDigit() {
    var randomEl = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
    randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomEl;
    return randomEl;
}
let randomNumber = 0;
generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
  randomNumber = randomDigit()
  console.log("Random Number is:", randomNumber);
  console.log(randomNumberDisplayEl.value);
});
```

Comment: Actually, I need the `randomNumber` as a global variable so that I can use it anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you had the JS code in the CSS section, I put it in the JS section and removed the useless code in the end (addEventListener doesn’t return what the fuction does, the randomNumber should be stored from the function.) and it works. In order to generate 4-digit codes, it needs to generate numbers greater or equal to 1000 or to add leading zeroes.

```js
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");
var randomNumber;

function randomDigit() {
  randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 9000 + 1000);
  randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomNumber;
}

generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", randomDigit);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pin Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/raw/upload/v1628938996/StackOverflow/style_til9dq.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="pin-generator half-width">
                    <input class="form-control" id="random-number-display" type="text">
                    <button class="generate-btn" id="generate-btn">Generate Pin</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notify-section pb-3" id="notify-section">
            <p class="notify" id="notify-wrong">❌ Pin Didn't Match, Please try again</p>
            <p class="notify" id="notify-right">✅ Pin Matched... Secret door is opening for you</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP said "_I need the `randomNumber` as a global variable_". There's no such variable in your code that does that.

Comment: I added the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `randomNumber` before the `randomDigit()` function, and set its value to the random number, generated by the function.

Note: `randomNumber` will be `undefined` before the first button click. You can initialize it with some default value, if you want to.

```js
var randomNumberDisplayEl = document.getElementById("random-number-display");
var generateBtnEl = document.getElementById("generate-btn");

var randomNumber;

function randomDigit() {
  var randomEl = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
  randomNumberDisplayEl.value = randomEl;
  randomNumber = randomEl;
}

generateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  randomDigit();
  /* For Logging purposes*/
  console.log("Random Number is:", randomNumber);
  console.log(randomNumberDisplayEl.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pin Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/raw/upload/v1628938996/StackOverflow/style_til9dq.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="pin-generator half-width">
          <input class="form-control" id="random-number-display" type="text">
          <button class="generate-btn" id="generate-btn">Generate Pin</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notify-section pb-3" id="notify-section">
      <p class="notify" id="notify-wrong">❌ Pin Didn't Match, Please try again</p>
      <p class="notify" id="notify-right">✅ Pin Matched... Secret door is opening for you</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```